# tooltip was hidden by pinned column

Tags: tooltip, ag-grid, ngx-bootstrap, ag-grid-ng2

**visions:**

- angular: 2.4.9
- ag-grid-angular: 16.0.0
- bootstrap: 4.0.0-alpha.5
- ngx-bootstrap: 1.6.6

I use ag-grid to frozen the first two column of table, and then overwrite tooltip width which is longer than the second column. Then it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOqmv.png)

the right of tooltip was covered by columns.

I tried to set

`z-index: 99999 !import`

but not work. Does anyone know?

Comment: can you reproduce this in plunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append tooltip to body.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
            tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
            container="body">
```

Add container="body" attribute with the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to change the width by a custom class then you can override the styles using below code in your CSS file. I have changed your plunker

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/hbrjgaKArGx34rVRzNOH?p=preview
```

Example

```
.tooltip-inner {max-width: 205px;}
```

Comment: @Y.Ping - did you check my plunker link?

Comment: yes, I am sure. You removed /deep/, so the default style can not work either.